# How to bundle vendor CSS files into a React app with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, webpack, css-modules

I have some 3rd party libs, like Mapbox GL, which are installed via npm and have some CSS files they rely on in their work.

As for Mapbox GL, there is `mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css` in `node_modules`. I have index.html which is used as the entry point for my React app and contains a link to a CSS file with some defaults.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/core.css">
```

All other CSS rules are provided by CSS modules, so I have a single CSS file in a React UI component folder and import it from the component like this:

```
import * as style from './MyComponent.css';
```

How do I import vendor CSS files, like Mapbox GL example above and make the rules from it apply to the app?

Comment: If you use Webpack already, could you put the content of webpack.config.js?

Answer (score 0):

1. If your vendor css files are *specific* to a component, you can import them directly into your component, like this:

   ```
   // Component1.js
   import React from 'react';
   ...
   import 'vendor/path/to/styles.css';
   ...
   ```
2. If you want to import a general css file (such as normalize.css), you can import them into your top-level html view. I usually have a JSX file which is transpiled by webpack to `index.html`. So you can do this:

   ```
   // index.jsx (transpiled to index.html)
   <style
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
       __html: require('!css-loader!normalize.css/normalize.css'),
     }}
   />
   ```
3. Or, if you have pure HTML, you can let webpack do it for you using the [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader)

---

For your reference, this is my webpack.config:

```
webpackConfig = {
  module: {
    rules = [
      {
        // excluding for node-modules
        test: /.css$/,
        exclude: path.resolve('./node_modules'),
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              camelCase: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
            },
          },
          'postcss-custom-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        // only for node-modules
        test: /.css$/,
        include: path.resolve('./node_modules'),
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-custom-loader'],
      },
...
}
```

Comment: I still cannot figure it out. Im trying to import vendor css into my component, ie import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'; However i dont get the styles in my app, I only get them if i use a cdn in my index.html. Can u let me know if something is wrong? 

https://gist.github.com/foodaka/6c65b4b96d5cef1fc7f1ae6ec6e18aca